# JavaScript - decrease div width continuously after fixed intervals

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a JavaScript noob and I'm trying to accomplish the following task:

1. A div that behaves like a button whose width (BG) increases on every
   click (Think of a progress bar which increases with every click) by a certain amount, say 10% increase in progress on every click
2. After the parent div width is full, there should be a
   10-second delay after which the div starts shrinking at a constant rate again.(Kind of like a reverse progress bar)
3. When the width is
   decreasing, the user should be able to click on the div and start
   increasing it again until it reaches the full width.

Please check the below image for reference:

[image]

I have accomplished Step 1 and I think Step 3 will take care of itself once I'm able to implement Step 2.

**Please help me with the 2nd step, (continuously decreasing width of the background div).**

My code is as follows:

```js
var paddleBtn = document.getElementById('paddleBtn');
var paddleC = document.getElementById('paddleC');
if (paddleC) {
  paddleC.style.width = "0px";
}
if (paddleBtn) {
  paddleBtn.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  paddleBtn.onclick = function() {
    if ((parseInt(paddleC.style.width) + 5) < paddleC.parentElement.offsetWidth) {
      var widthC = parseInt(paddleC.style.width) + 20;
      paddleC.style.width = String(widthC).concat('px');
      if (paddleC.offsetWidth > paddleC.parentElement.offsetWidth) {
        paddleC.style.width = paddleC.parentElement.offsetWidth;
      }
    }
    if (parseInt(paddleC.style.width) >= paddleC.parentElement.offsetWidth - 5) {
      paddleC.style.backgroundColor = "#B3DDE0";
      paddleC.style.width = paddleC.parentElement.offsetWidth - 2;
    }
  };
}
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid Black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}

.cooldown {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}

.labelT {
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Arial", Times, serif;
  width: inherit;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="./script.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='btn' id='paddleBtn'>
    <div class='labelT'>Paddle</div>
    <div class='cooldown' id='paddleC'></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Sorry for the ugly code, as I said I'm still trying to get a hang of the JavaScript basics. I had to modfiy the code sample to make it run on StackOverflow.

Please help!

Thanks!
Viksit

Comment: You should take a look at [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)

Comment: @Titus setTimeout did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. You can change interval time according to your requirement, I put 3 seconds for now. Thanks

```js
   

 var paddleInterval;
    var paddleBtn = document.getElementById('paddleBtn');
    var paddleC = document.getElementById('paddleC');
    function decreasePaddle(){
        var widthC = parseInt(paddleC.style.width) - 20;
        paddleC.style.width = String(widthC).concat('px');
        paddleC.style.backgroundColor = "#DCDCDC";
        if (parseInt(paddleC.style.width) <= 0){
clearInterval(paddleInterval);
}
    }
    if (paddleC) {
      paddleC.style.width = "0px";
    }
    if (paddleBtn) {
      paddleBtn.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      paddleBtn.onclick = function() {
        if ((parseInt(paddleC.style.width) + 5) < paddleC.parentElement.offsetWidth) {
          clearInterval(paddleInterval);
          var widthC = parseInt(paddleC.style.width) + 20;
          paddleC.style.width = String(widthC).concat('px');
          if (paddleC.offsetWidth > paddleC.parentElement.offsetWidth) {
            paddleC.style.width = paddleC.parentElement.offsetWidth;
          }
        }
        if (parseInt(paddleC.style.width) >= paddleC.parentElement.offsetWidth - 5) {
          paddleC.style.backgroundColor = "#B3DDE0";
          paddleC.style.width = paddleC.parentElement.offsetWidth - 2;
          paddleInterval = setInterval(decreasePaddle, 3000);
        }
      };
    }
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid Black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
}

.cooldown {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease;
}

.labelT {
  z-index: 2;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Arial", Times, serif;
  width: inherit;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="./script.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='btn' id='paddleBtn'>
    <div class='labelT'>Paddle</div>
    <div class='cooldown' id='paddleC'></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with setInterval. Remember to assign it to a reachable variable (IE: var interval = setInterval(..);) so you can reference it and cancel every time you need it (IE: when user clicks -> setTimeout/setInterval 10s -> setInterval 200ms that changes width until 0)